# software for laptop heat diagnostics

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, temperature, cooling, diagnostic

I had my laptop for about 6 months. Yesterday i hit shutdown and left the room and apparently it shut down due to temperature. Right now my laptop suddenly got hot fast.

What can i do about this and what software can i use to monitor the heat which may help me deduce what is causing it to heat up. Room temperature doesnt seem to affect it. I wasnt running any games yesterday. so i am quiet confused.

Answer (score 1):

Real Temp
http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/

Speed Fan
http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php

Dude, just a friendly advise. If it is getting very hot, go and get it repaired. My laptop just got screwed up and I cannot even install ANY operating system. Apparently it was because my laptop charger was providing low voltage which burned up some circuits....

Comment: I am working on that right now.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few utilities available for observing various sensors, the one I use is [HWiNFO32](http://www.hwinfo.com/) It has a portable version, so you don't have to install it.

Using a utility such as this, or the ones described above, may help to pinpoint where the temperature build up is happening. As to why it's happening, that may be a harder question to answer. It may simply be due to clogged vents, there again, it may be a more serious thermal problem.

If the problem is one of overheating, I'd be inclined to take a look at your warranty, as the laptop is only six months old. To be honest, even if it's out of warranty, unless you feel technically able and have the appropriate tools, I'd do as Ranhiru suggested and get it looked at asap.